# date value is not getting set properly

Tags: php, database, laravel, date, laravel-5.3

i am using two types of dates in my form one with the 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format which is for created_at,updated_at,deleted_at and one is for valid_to 'Y-m-d' the problem is my created_at are getting set properly but when i try to save the **valid_from** it's value doesn't get set and it saves **0000-00-00** in the database i have tried a couple of things but non of it seems to be working
Controller code

```
 $input = $request->all();
//        if($request->input('valid_from')) {
//            $date = explode("-", $request->input('valid_from'));
//            $dob = $date['2'] . '-' . $date['1'] . '-' . $date['0'];
//        }
//        $input->valid_from = $dob;
//        return $request->all();
//        $date= $input->valid_from;
//        $date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->current_date);
//
//        $day = $date->day;
//        $month = $date->month;
//        $year = $date->year;
//        dd($request);
//        $date = $input->valid_from;
//        $input->valid_from = date('M d,Y',$date);
////        $date = explode('-', $input->valid_from);
////        $input->valid_from = $date['2'].'-'.$date['1'].'-'.$date['0'];
        Promotion::create($input);
```

Model code

```
protected $fillable = ['valid_from'];
    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
// 'valid_from',


    ];
//    protected $valid = ['valid_from'];
//    public function getFormattedValidFromAttribute($valid) {
//        $valid = new Carbon($valid);
//        return $valid->format('d-m-Y');
////        return $this->valid_from->format('d-m-Y');
//    }
//    public function getFormattedValidToAttribute() {
//        return $this->valid_to->format('d-m-Y');
//    }
//    protected function getDateFormat()
//    {
////        return 'U';
//        return 'd-m-Y ';
//    }
```

Migration

```
$table->date('valid_from');
```

Comment: Try like this: `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: @HirenGohel in controller or model

Comment: Where you want it to be! :)

Comment: @HirenGohel tried it in controller like 
$date= $input->valid_from;
        \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d');
        $input->valid_from = $date;
but it returned with an error 
ErrorException in PromotionController.php line 46:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: So is it worked or gives any errors?

Comment: See `$input->valid_from` is not null

Comment: @HirenGohel the funny thing is it's not null the value is getting sent to the database

Comment: And saved it to DB with giving this error?

Comment: @HirenGohel the value is getting save in the database but like "0000-00-00" but not with the value that i am trying to give it

Comment: `dd($input->valid_from);` see what value it gives you?

Comment: @HirenGohel this is the value that i got "17-03-2018"

Comment: Just try it like: `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($input->valid_from)->format('Y-m-d');` This is worked for me!!

Comment: @HirenGohel tried it \Carbon\Carbon::parse($input->valid_from)->format('Y-m-d'); still gives ErrorException in PromotionController.php line 40:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Ok, error are coming from other code, because this is works for me! Try to debug it!

Comment: @HirenGohel everything else is working like it supposed to, but could be going wrong???

Comment: I think you got the answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you followed the date_format of  your column `valid_from`.

```
$input = $request->except('valid_from');
$input['valid_from'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->input('valid_from')));
Promotion::create($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the dd($input->valid_from); as "17-03-2018" .Its in d-m-Y format.

Try this

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->valid_from)->format('Y-m-d');
```